# Create Sequence using Min and Max Numbers from another table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

How do I create a sequence list using numbers from another table. I am using the below syntax but I'm just wondering how do I start with the minimum value from another table then create the sequence to the maximum value from the other table.

```
CREATE SEQUENCE SequenceList
  AS DECIMAL
  START WITH *(select the min value from another table)*
  INCREMENT BY 1
  MINVALUE *(select the min value from another table)*
  MAXVALUE *(select the max value from another table)*
```

I've tried using a select statement for START WITH, MINVALUE, and MAXVALUE but it doesn't work.

Comment: The grammar https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-sequence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#syntax says they need to be constants, so you will need dynamic SQL

Comment: Sorry if this is obvious but how would I do it with dynamic SQL? Or what is the syntax for it?

Comment: Without specifying precision/scale it is treated as `DECIMAL(18,0)` if anyone else was wondering! So should likely just be a `bigint` as 8 bytes and bigger range vs 9 bytes

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. The datatype from the other table is a decimal so I just assumed that I needed to create the sequence as a decimal. Please let me know if that isn't the case. Thanks.

Comment: What is the use case for this sequence? You set the range to the min and max from the other table. And then what? How are you planning on using this?  You can use the sequence to generate a value that possibly matches that of another row in a different table?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use dynamic SQL.

```sql
DECLARE @min bigint, @max bigint;

SELECT
  @min = CAST(MIN(value) AS bigint),
  @max = CAST(MAX(value) AS bigint)
FROM anothertable;

DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = '
CREATE SEQUENCE SequenceList
  AS DECIMAL(0)
  START WITH ' + CONVERT(nvarchar(max), @min) + '
  INCREMENT BY 1
  MINVALUE ' + CONVERT(nvarchar(max), @min) + '
  MAXVALUE ' + CONVERT(nvarchar(max), @max) + ';'

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

Kinda weird to use `decimal` for a `SEQUENCE` but whatever....