# How to alter sequence in SQL Server with last inserted id

Tags: sql-server, sequence

I store test data with fixed ID (regarding FK needed) in several tables.
After inserted, I'd like to set the sequence correctly.

I've tried without success the following SQL

```
ALTER SEQUENCE SEQ_MY_TABLE 
RESTART WITH SELECT MAX(ID) + 1 FROM MY_TABLE;
```

Comment: That would be a very bad idea. `MAX+1` guarantees collisions. Why do you want this?

Comment: fetch max id value first and then generate dynamic sql string that alters sequence

Comment: [You need dynamic SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76971041/61305) but that doesn't make it a good idea.